# Jerking storyboard animation with content overflow

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to create an application with an untypical navigation menu. This screen shows what I've done so far.

[image]

When I navigate through my app, the current content fades and slides out and the new one fades in. Here are my storyboards:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MainSlideIn">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MainContentPane"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                        BeginTime="0:0:0.2"/>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="MainSlideOut">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MainContentPaneHelper"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MainContentPaneTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateX"
                        From="0" To="-50" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
```

This works fine. As long as the content fits in my container. Otherwise it totaly jerks. Here is the second page:

[image]

And this is how I change my content and begin the storyboards:

```
if (_currentMenuItem == null || _currentMenuItem != MenuItem)
{
    if(_currentMenuItem!= null)
        _currentMenuItem.Background = TransparentBrush;
    _currentMenuItem = MenuItem;
    _currentMenuItem.Background = MenuItemAccentBrush;

    // Yes I know that this isn't the best way^^
    // But it works
    int i = -1;
    if (MainContentPane.Content is Overview)
        i = 0;
    else if (MainContentPane.Content is Todayview)
        i = 1;
    else if (MainContentPane.Content is Tasksview)
        i = 3;

    MainContentPane.Opacity = 0;
    MainContentPaneHelper.Content = null;
    MainContentPane.Content = control;

    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            MainContentPaneHelper.Content = _overview;
            break;
        case 1:
            MainContentPaneHelper.Content = _today;
            break;
        case 3:
            MainContentPaneHelper.Content = _tasks;
            break;
    }

    MainSlideIn.Begin();
    MainSlideOut.Begin();
}
```

## UPDATE 2:

This are my container:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
      Margin="70,0,0,0">

    <ContentControl x:Name="MainContentPane" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainContentPaneHelper" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="MainContentPaneTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
        </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your storyboards look fine, they should be handled by the compositor thread and be smooth. I suspect changing the `Content` of your `MainContentPane` or `MainContentPaneHelper` somehow forces the objects position and size to be re-computed. What containers are you using? Grid, Canvas, StackPanel, ...? If you're using a Grid, are your columns set with a fixed size or auto size?

Comment: I've updated my post :)
I'm using ContentControls

Comment: But your ContentControls are put inside of what kind of container? ;)

Comment: Inside a grid: <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
              Margin="70,0,0,0">

Comment: And how are defined the columns? Fixed width or Auto?

Comment: I've updated my posting. There are no cols